# Is there example of ZeroMQ XSUB socket for PHP

Tags: php, sockets, zeromq

I tried to connect to ZMQ XPUB socket (using http://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.zmq.php) ,but there is no result, code below:

```
    $context = new \ZMQContext();
    $subscriber = $context->getSocket(\ZMQ::SOCKET_XSUB);
    $subscriber->connect("tcp://11.98.26.100:7775");
    $subscriber->send("\1user_100001.");

    $string = $subscriber->recv();
    echo $string;
```

The process is nothing received. I found in  Is there example of implementation the connection through XSUB socket for PHP ? I looked in [http://zguide.zeromq.org/php:_start](http://zguide.zeromq.org/php%3a_start) but there is no exapmle for XSUB socket.

Comment: Where's the code for the publisher socket? You showed only half the code in question.

Comment: Also, if examples are lacking, you can always go to the git repository and check tests. [This test](https://github.com/mkoppanen/php-zmq/blob/0ed51c55e3cb40183a6fd0ae7abc655795a8a09c/tests/028-xpub.phpt) contains code you require to test your XPUB/XSUB.